# nginx redirects all files with or without extensions except a few

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite

How to match all files with **or without** extension, except those with the extension txt, pdf, jpeg.

On my Nginx configuration this downloads all the files without any restriction.

```
location ~ .+(?<!\.pdf|\.txt|\.jpeg)$ {
        
    auth_request /auth.php;
    error_page 401 = @login;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved I auth.php was not included as an exception which would cause a loop.

```
location ~ .+(?<!/|auth.php|.txt|.pdf|.jpeg|.jpg|.png)$ { 

    auth_request /auth.php;
    error_page 401 = @login;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about defining two locations? E.g.

```
location ~ \.(pdf|txt|jpeg)$ {
    # handle those with the extension pdf, txt, jpeg
}
location / {
    # handle all files with or without extension
}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, thanks for your help.